# How can I add onclick event to a table column?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, dom-events

I'm trying to add an `onclick` event to a table column using JavaScript. For example, an `onclick` event enabled on the first or second column! The following function is for rows, but I need to edit this function for specific columns.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler = function (row) {
            return function () {
                var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
                var id = cell.innerHTML;
                alert("id:" + id);
            };
        };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see a single question mark in your "question"

Comment: Jamie Taylotr. I edited my question. Is that ok? :)

Comment: maybe add class to cells you want event on then bind to class.

Comment: @gwillie How can I use class in this function?(what is the syntax of that?)

Comment: make a class name for every "td" as the columns number and check it onClick on any 'd' tag !!

Answer (score 3):

Try this working soln.

```
function addRowHandlers() {
 var table = document.getElementById("tableId");
 var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    
 for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
   var currentRow = table.rows[i];
   currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
 }
}

function createClickHandler(row) {
  return function() { 
    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];// if you put 0 here then it will return first column of this row
    var id = cell.innerHTML;
    alert("id:" + id);
  };
}

addRowHandlers();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uVdb3/11/)**

Answer (score 1):

adding class to affected rows/columns would be more flexible.

if you know the rows/columns do something like this (untested), for rows 1 and 2:

```
var $table = jQuery('#tableId');
var $rows = jQuery('tr:nth-child(0),tr:nth-child(1)', $table);
$rows
    .addClass('event-1')
    .click(function()
    {
      // do what on click event
      alert(jQuery(this).html());
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to return row and column number using jQuery, it must be helpful
[Jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/cha9chi/KkJBX/)

```
$('td').on('click',function() {
                var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));
                var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
                alert('Row: ' + row + ', Column: ' + col);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attach only the single `onclick` handler to your table and then recognize the clicked column, this technique is called [event delegation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate):

```js
document.getElementById("tableId").onclick = columnHandler;

function columnHandler(e) {
    e = e || window.event; //for IE87 backward compatibility
    var t = e.target || e.srcElement; //IE87 backward compatibility
    while (t.nodeName != 'TD' && t.nodeName != 'TH' && t.nodeName != 'TABLE') {
        t = t.parentNode;
    }
    if (t.nodeName == 'TABLE') {
        return;
    }
    var c = t.parentNode.cells;
    var j = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<c.length; i++){
        if (c[i] == t) {
            j = i;
        }
    }
    alert('You clicked on row #'+(j+1)+ ' , cell content = '+t.innerHTML);
}
```

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ma9H/)